# How to make a programatic scrollviews container height the exact size of its content in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

My problem is as follows:

The height of *contentView* is taller than its subviews, so although the subviews of *contentView* don't take up the entire screen vertically, you can still scroll past the content.

How can I set the height of *contentView* to match the height of its subviews, so that way if the screen is large enough vertically to fit the content, you can't scroll, but if the screen is smaller or a keyboard signal is sent, then you can scroll vertically?

I understand the problem is with the height constraint in the *contentView.anchor*, but I don't know how to fix it and I haven't been able to find any answers.

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let contentView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    configureScrollView()
    configureUI()
    
}

func configureScrollView() {
            
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                      left: view.leftAnchor,
                      bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                      right: view.rightAnchor)
    
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor,
                       left: scrollView.leftAnchor,
                       bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor,
                       right: scrollView.rightAnchor,
                       width: view.frame.size.width,
                       height: view.frame.size.height)
}

func configureUI() {
    
    contentView.addSubview(previewTitleLabel)
    previewTitleLabel.anchor(top: contentView.topAnchor,
                             left: contentView.leftAnchor,
                             right: contentView.rightAnchor,
                             paddingTop: 20,
                             paddingLeft: 20,
                             paddingRight: 20,
                             height: 20)

    contentView.addSubview(previewView)
    previewView.anchor(top: previewTitleLabel.bottomAnchor,
                       left: contentView.leftAnchor,
                       right: contentView.rightAnchor,
                       paddingTop: 20,
                       paddingLeft: 20,
                       paddingRight: 20) // Has dynamic height

    contentView.addSubview(detailsTitleLabel)
    detailsTitleLabel.anchor(top: previewView.bottomAnchor,
                             left: contentView.leftAnchor,
                             right: contentView.rightAnchor,
                             paddingTop: 20,
                             paddingLeft: 20,
                             paddingRight: 20,
                             height: 20)

    contentView.addSubview(descriptionView)
    descriptionView.anchor(top: detailsTitleLabel.bottomAnchor,
                           left: contentView.leftAnchor,
                           right: contentView.rightAnchor,
                           paddingTop: 20,
                           paddingLeft: 20,
                           paddingRight: 20,
                           height: 278)
}
```

Comment: Think about https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p362scrollViewInCode2b/ch20p670scrollViewInCode2/ViewController.swift

Comment: Or, if you're going to use a content view, https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p363scrollViewInCode3/ch20p670scrollViewInCode3/ViewController.swift case 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple tips:

1. Go through a half-dozen or so scroll view tutorials, so you understand how they work.
2. Go through a half-dozen or so auto-layout tutorials, so you understand how constraints work.
3. Use standard constraint syntax instead of your `.anchor()` "helper" until you fully understand how constraints work. This also lets you "group" your constraints logically, as you'll see in this example code.
4. During layout development, give your UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easy to see frames.

So, example code:

```
class ExampleScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let contentView = UIView()
    
    let previewTitleLabel = UILabel()
    let previewView = UIView()
    let detailsTitleLabel = UILabel()
    let descriptionView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configureScrollView()
        configureUI()
        
        // use some background colors so we can easily see frames
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
        previewTitleLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        previewView.backgroundColor = .green
        detailsTitleLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        descriptionView.backgroundColor = .green

        previewTitleLabel.text = "Preview Title Label"
        detailsTitleLabel.text = "Details Title Label"
    }
    
    func configureScrollView() {

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // reference to scrollView's contentLayoutGuide
        let svContentLG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        // reference to scrollView's frameLayoutGuide
        let svFrameLG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain scroll view to full safe area
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),

            // constrain content view to all 4 sides of scroll view's content layout guide
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svContentLG.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svContentLG.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svContentLG.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svContentLG.bottomAnchor),
            
            // we want vertical scrolling,
            //  so constrain width of content view to scroll view's frame
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svFrameLG.widthAnchor),

        ])

    }
    
    func configureUI() {
        
        [previewTitleLabel, previewView, detailsTitleLabel, descriptionView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // horizontal constraints
            
            // all 4 subviews will be constrained
            //  Leading and Trailing to the contentView
            //  with 20-pts "padding" on left and right
            previewTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            previewTitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            previewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            previewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            detailsTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            detailsTitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            descriptionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            descriptionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // vertical spacing constraints
            
            // previewTitleLabel Top 20-pts from contentView Top
            previewTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // previewView Top 20-pts from previewTitleLabel Bottom
            previewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewTitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // detailsTitleLabel Top 20-pts from previewView Bottom
            detailsTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // descriptionView Top 20-pts from detailsTitleLabel Bottom
            descriptionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailsTitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // complete the vertical spacing constraints by
            //  constraining descriptionView Bottom 20-pts from contentView Bottom
            descriptionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // vertical height constraints
            
            // previewTitleLabel Height: 20
            previewTitleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
            
            // previewView Height: 20
            previewView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
            
            // detailsTitleLabel Height: 20
            detailsTitleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
            
            // descriptionView Height: 270
            descriptionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 270.0),

        ])

    }
    
}
```

Result:

[image]

If I change the Height of `previewView` also to `270`:

```
previewView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 270.0),
```

we get this result:

[image]

and we can scroll up to see the bottom of the content:

[image]